# Difference between 1 CTRL-G and :pwd, quotation marks?

Tags: working-directory

The commands `1 CTRL-G` and `:pwd` return related but different results:

```
1 CTRL-G    "~/dev/src/tiff.c" 170 lines --15%--
:pwd        /home/user/src
```

Of course, `CTRL-G` returns the file, not the working directory, but interestingly enough uses the tilde (~) shortcut to the home directory, but `pwd` does not give the tilde, but expands it out. Also, `CTRL-G` surrounds the path in quotation marks, but `pwd` does not.

What is the significance of these differences? For example, why would CTRL-G have quotation marks around it, but pwd not?

Comment: Don't know if these can be answered unless the dev(s) show up and reveal their thinking! I know `:pwd` comes from `getcwd()` which returns a string type which must not have quotes around it. `Ctrl-G` on the other hand is purely for human consumption thus probably intentionally prettified/delimeted with quotes. But that's pure conjecture!

Comment: I think @BLayer is right: `CRTL-G` is only used to display information to the user its output is easy to read for a human but not that easy to parse in code. `pwd` can be used in code to easily get a data just like `line('$')` and `line('.') * 100 / line('$')` which show the remaining data of `CTRL-G`